# SQL - Select from only Columns which contain x number of distinct values from table?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table which has several hundred columns in it. Each column is the spend in a different category and each row is a customer. If a customer did not spend in the category, the value is by default 0 else the value is the amount spent. There are likely many columns where no one has ever spent anything or spend is only by a few customers.

Is there SQL code that will dynamically select the columns based on at least having 5 rows (Customers) where the amount spent is greater than zero? I want the code to be dynamic such that the output table will automatically add columns over time based on people spending more in these categories. Can SQL even handle this?

Assuming Cat5 has at least 5 customers with values but Cat 3 and 4 do not.

```
ID              Cat1    Cat2    Cat3     Cat4    Cat5
cust1           $200    $300     $0       $0      $0 
cust2           $50     $30      $0       $0      $0 
cust3           $20    $1000     $0       $0      $0 
...             ...      ...     ...     ...     ...
cust100         $32     $32      $0       $0      $32
```

desired ouput:

```
ID              Cat1    Cat2    Cat5
cust1           $200    $300     $0 
cust2           $50     $30      $0 
cust3           $20    $1000     $0 
...             ...     ...      ...
cust100         $32     $32      $32
```

Code might look something like (though naturally this isn't really that close):

```
Select (Case when Count(distinct(*)) > 5 then column else None end) from table1
```

In python I could do it like the below, however the result must be usable within Snowflake/sql as we are not allowed outside compute resources:

```
df = df[[column for column in df.columns if len(df[column].unique()) > 5]]
```

I have been googling for a while though with no explicit results. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible by just writing a query. Some programming will be required. Have you tried putting the logic in a stored procedure

There may be some optimization opportunities. I did not spend time to further optimize and beautify the code. I probably will do those before moving the code to production. But the idea here is to have the SQL procedure check each column and see if the column count is greater than five, if yes then create another table with those columns only and insert rows with those columns.

Please see if this will work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure DYNAMICCOL(COLVAL FLOAT)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
AS
$$
// GET THE COUNT OF EACH COLUMN WHERE THE COLUMN VALUE IS GREATER THAN ZERO

var cmd = "SELECT count(COL1) COUNTCOL1 from t1 where COL1> :1 group by COL1;";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd,
          binds: [COLVAL]
          }
          );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next();
COL1COUNT = result1.getColumnValue(1);

var cmd = "SELECT count(COL2) COUNTCOL1 from t1 where COL2> :1 group by COL2;";
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement(
          {
          sqlText: cmd,
          binds: [COLVAL]
          }
          );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
result1.next();
COL2COUNT = result1.getColumnValue(1);


var COL_LIST='';

// IF COL COUNT IS GREATER THAN ZERO CONCATENATE THEM AND CREATE ANOTHER TABLE WITH THOSE COLUMNS ONLY
//ALSO INSERT RECORDS INTO THIS NEW TABLE FROM THE ORIGINAL TABLE

if (COL1COUNT > 5 )
{
    COL_LIST = 'COL1 NUMBER, ';
    COL_LIST1 = 'COL1 ,';
}

if (COL2COUNT > 5 )
{
    COL_LIST = COL_LIST +'COL2 NUMBER';
    COL_LIST1 = COL_LIST1 +'COL2 ';
}

var my_sql_command1 = "CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE T1TEMP (" + COL_LIST +");";
var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:my_sql_command1});
statement1.execute();

var my_sql_command1 = "INSERT INTO T1TEMP SELECT "+ COL_LIST1 + "FROM T1"
var statement1 = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText:my_sql_command1});
statement1.execute();


return my_sql_command1;
$$
;

call DYNAMICCOL(0);
select * from T1TEMP;
```

Comment: How would you do this with a stored procedure?